# Why doesn't my GoogleApiClient work after I log in one time?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client

I've implemented a `GoogleApiClient` for Google Plus sign in and it works great the first time around. If I head back to the log in `Activity` afterwards though, the `Activity` will just `finish` on its own. Sometimes it'll take a moment, but most of the time it's right away. I noticed that when I just don't call `GoogleApiClient.connect` in `Activity.onStart` or comment out `GoogleApiClient.Builder.addConnectionCallbacks`, then there is no crash, but obviously I can't use G+ sign in anymore.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mApiClient != null && !mApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mApiClient != null && mApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mApiClient.disconnect();
        mApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
        mApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this);
        mApiClient = null;
    }
}
```

My callbacks are standard as well.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                mSignInProgress = resultCode == RESULT_OK ? STATE_SIGN_IN : STATE_DEFAULT;
                if (mApiClient != null && !mApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mApiClient.connect();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        if (mApiClient != null && !mApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mSignInProgress != STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
            mSignInIntent = connectionResult.getResolution();
            if (mSignInProgress == STATE_SIGN_IN) resolveLogin();
        }
        if (mApiClient != null) {
            mApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

private void resolveLogin() {
    if (mSignInIntent == null) return;
    try {
        mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
        startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
        if (mApiClient != null && !mApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything I've done is largely based off of [Google's example](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/plus/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java). So, just be clear. I log in once and as is well. Afterwards, if I start that `Activity` again, it will just `Activity.finish` after a very brief moment.

Comment: This is the exact same problem I am having! Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the BaseGameUtil, it is very easy to setup and will take care of all your logging in and out, with optional login/out buttons, you can set it up by following [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).I have recently set this up and it proved to be a very useful set of features.